# What is the meaning of the idiom “au bon pain” ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison

What does the phrase/idiom “au bon pain” mean?

I am translating it as “with the good bread” or “to the good bread”.

How has this idiomatic expression arrived?

Answer (score 7):

This is not a specific idiom, it's just a rather frequent name for a bakery.

Lots of shop names will start with *à*, *à* is a preposition that here introduces the place one is at, as in:

> Je suis à la maison (I'm at home).

Naming the bakery *Au bon pain* is a hint to potential customers that's the place where they'll be able to buy good bread. Naming the bakery *Au bon pain* puts the stress on the shop, the environment (the salespeople, the decoration etc...) , whereas *Le bon pain* (which can be found as well as a bakery name) puts more stress on the product.

In the same way in France you will find shop names such as:
*À la bonne pêche* for a fishmonger's.
*À la bonne fourchette* for a restaurant.
*À la bonne bière* for a café.
*Au dé d'argent* for a haberdashery.
etc...

You do not say in what context you have encountered the words so we can also imagine them used in a figurative context. For example I could say "*chez nous c'est au bon pain*", meaning that in my house we eat good bread. It still designates a place where good bread can be found.

Comment: You might also cite *Au bon beurre* by Jean Dutourd.

Comment: or *Au bonheur des dames* by Zola.

Comment: and there is the famous *Au Lion d'Or* (at the Golden Lion) for an hotel, as it is phonetically "Au lit on dort" (at bed we sleep)... ; )

Comment: C'est vrai, mais même sans levant son verre, on peut toujours proposer un French toast au bon pain!

Comment: *À la bonne fourchette* is the coolest literature reference here. :)

Comment: Not sure, if this was already implied in the answer (though it likely motivated the question): "Aubonpain" is the name of a restaurant chain widely present in Canada and northern US - a kind of French-styled McDo/Burgerking: https://www.aubonpain.com/

Comment: @RogerVadim  Unless when referring to its URL, you should always separate words with spaces in *Au bon pain*.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord.

Comment: @RogerVadim The question was indeed likely motivated by the chain name. None rightly assumed it was the name of a bakery but was probably unaware of the NA chain. That doesn't affect her reply correctness.

Comment: @jlliagre I didn't mean to question the validity of the reply, but I thought it was a relevant piece of information.

Comment: @RogerVadim It is certainly relevant unfortunately the OP vanished in the meantime so is unlikely to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the translation of a Barbara Weldens song, where it is said that the following:
“Me réclame un bon de pain”
Means “Ask me for a bread voucher”
https://en.muztext.com/lyrics/barbara-weldens-du-pain-pour-les-reveille-matin
This sounds somewhat bizarre but the song does have rather fantastic lyrics.

Comment: "***Au** bon pain*" and "***un** bon **de** pain*" are substantially different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).